# Mongoose won't install in an exercise at Cloud 9. Is using Node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Here's the complete response when attempting to install Mongoose -

```
npm WARN package.json workspace@1.0.0 No repository field.
npm WARN package.json workspace@1.0.0 No README data
mongoose@4.7.7 ../node_modules/mongoose
├── ms@0.7.2
├── sliced@1.0.1
├── hooks-fixed@1.2.0
├── regexp-clone@0.0.1
├── muri@1.1.1
├── mpromise@0.5.5
├── kareem@1.2.0
├── mpath@0.2.1
├── bson@1.0.4
├── mquery@2.0.0 (sliced@0.0.5, debug@2.2.0, bluebird@2.10.2)
├── mongodb@2.2.21 (es6-promise@3.2.1, readable-stream@2.1.5, mongodb-core@2.1.6)
└── async@2.1.4 (lodash@4.17.4)
```

Frankly I don't get it as this is just but one of several projects that I have successfully installed Mongoose into. It already has the comerr-dev file so that's not it.

I've also used `sudo apt-get install -y`  and still can't install Mongoose.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

install mongoose using this command in you path file where your app.js and package.json exist.
**command** - **npm install mongoose --save**.
  "--save" command will save your mongoose lib and directly add it into you package.json file.
i have provided you a screenshot below.as if i wanted to install mongoose in my workspace/v1 path directory, i simply installed it by using command mentioned above
here is an screen shot[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eMQvW.png)

Comment: I appreciate your tip, however this project does not require anything but Mongoose, therefore the --save switch is not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

How, I don't know, but the files for Mongoose were installed in another directory further up the tree.

I have to accept responsibility because no one else was behind the keyboard.

Anyone to come after should consider this as a solution to a mysterious situation. Also, I was able to cut and paste Mongoose's nodules into the correct directory with no problem.